# How to visualize the attention vector with a text heatmap?

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working on an NLP research project and I want to visualize the output of the attention vector.

For example, the data looks like this:

```
def sample_data():
    
    sent = '''the USS Ronald Reagan - an aircraft carrier docked in Japan - during his tour of the region, vowing to "defeat any attack and meet any use of conventional or nuclear weapons with an overwhelming and effective American response".'''

    words    = sent.split()
    word_num = len(words)
    attention = [(x+1.)/word_num*100 for x in range(word_num)]
    
    return {'text': words, 'attention': attention}
```

which looks like this:

```
{'text': ['the', 'USS', 'Ronald', 'Reagan', '-', 'an', 'aircraft', 'carrier', 'docked', 'in', 'Japan', '-', 'during', 'his', 'tour', 'of', 'the', 'region,', 'vowing', 'to', '"defeat', 'any', 'attack', 'and', 'meet', 'any', 'use', 'of', 'conventional', 'or', 'nuclear', 'weapons', 'with', 'an', 'overwhelming', 'and', 'effective', 'American', 'response".'], 'attention': [2.564102564102564, 5.128205128205128, 7.6923076923076925, 10.256410256410255, 12.82051282051282, 15.384615384615385, 17.94871794871795, 20.51282051282051, 23.076923076923077, 25.64102564102564, 28.205128205128204, 30.76923076923077, 33.33333333333333, 35.8974358974359, 38.46153846153847, 41.02564102564102, 43.58974358974359, 46.15384615384615, 48.717948717948715, 51.28205128205128, 53.84615384615385, 56.41025641025641, 58.97435897435898, 61.53846153846154, 64.1025641025641, 66.66666666666666, 69.23076923076923, 71.7948717948718, 74.35897435897436, 76.92307692307693, 79.48717948717949, 82.05128205128204, 84.61538461538461, 87.17948717948718, 89.74358974358975, 92.3076923076923, 94.87179487179486, 97.43589743589743, 100.0]}
```

Each token is assigned to one float value (attention score). What are the options to visualize this data? Any library/tools available in any language R/Python/Js?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that would handle the long sentences great would be to print a colored sentence in the console. You can do so by printing escape characters in the console: `\033[38;2;255;0;0m test \033[0m` will print a red `test` in the console (rgb code (255, 0, 0)).
By using this idea, we can make a gradient from green to red (low to high attention) and print the text:

```py
import numpy as np

data = sample_data()

def colorFader(c1,c2,mix=0):
    return (1-mix)*np.array(c1) + mix*np.array(c2)
def colored(c, text):
    return "\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[0m".format(int(c[0]), int(c[1]), int(c[2]), text)

normalizer = max(dic["attention"])
output = ""
for word, attention in zip(dic["text"], dic["attention"]):
    color = colorFader([0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0], mix=attention/normalizer)
    output += colored(color, word)

print(output)
```

This solution would output something like this on the console:[image: colored console output]
I find this to be effective as a visualizer, but the fact that it does the visualization in the console might not be a good thing.

Another way would be to do a heatmap:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = sample_data()

# Create a pyplot figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Creating the heatmap image with the <plasma> colormap
img = ax.imshow([data["attention"]], cmap='plasma', aspect='auto', extent=[-1,1,-1,1])
# Setting the x_ticks position to be in the middle of the corresponding color
ax.set_xticks([-1 + (i+0.5)*2/len(data["text"]) for i in range(len(data["text"]))])
# Setting the x_ticks labels as the text, rotated to 80° for space purpose
ax.set_xticklabels(data["text"], rotation=80)
# Display the heatmap
plt.show()
```

This gives the following result (upon which you can modify some parameters such as the height, width, colors, etc...)[image]
If you have long sentences, this might not be the optimal solution though, as the ticks labels will be harder to see.